# Not able to view a webpage or connect to a service on a VM connected using OpenVPN, only able to perform Nmap scans

Tags: openvpn

I've tried asking this question in hack the box forum, but nothing has worked so far.

When I connect to a vulnerable machine using a tunneled IP using OpenVPN, all I'm able to do to a box is scan it (which is working fine), irrespective of the platform (for now I'm only on THM and HTB).

If there is a service open like FTP on any of the boxes, I might be able to connect to it, but would not be able to pull anything of off it.

Also if the box has a webpage available, it won't open. Directory fuzzing won't happen either for the url.

I've tried all of the troubleshooting steps, yet I've not been able to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to the community. We will need more information - what do you need to exploit in this CTF - is it known? Have you tried SMB enumeration?

Comment: for example, I took "soccer" in HTB or take "gaming server" in THM to TS this, they both didn't have an SMB port open in the scan. I'll probably be able to connect to it, because problem occurs whenever I make a request which involves a `get`

Comment: Have you been scanning with `sudo nmap`? I suggest also removing `-T4` `--min-rate` and similar flags if you get false positives or no ports at all. Also, what is "TS"?

Comment: Troubleshooting(TS)....So i did compare my nmap results to those of the writeups and they were on point. It's weird I know...

Comment: What is your routing table like? What error messages do you get? Does ping work? What is the nmap output?

Comment: ping does work. traceroute to the server was fine and no hops were left unrecorded. Nmap output came out exactly like [here](https://systemweakness.com/soccer-hack-the-box-f02665c71abe)

Comment: Is there some place I can upload a wireshark capture for you to analyze...I can upload that there and send you the link, if you'd like...